# Javascript form input value comparison to input max

Tags: javascript, validation, input, user-input

I have a `<form>` where I'm trying to compare the `value` and the `max` of an `input` so that if the `value` exceeds the `max` I'd apply different styling to the input (like a red border). Suppose I have an input like this:

```
<input id="inp_1" type="text" numeric-only="" max="50">
```

And let's assume I have three input values (9, 49 and 59). I'll come back to this is in a moment.

This is my js code that acquires the input and checks on the `value` and `max`:

```
var activeInpId = document.activeElement.id;
var activeInpVal = document.activeElement.value;
var activeInpMax = document.activeElement.max;
var pickElement = document.getElementById(activeInpId);
//console 1
console.log("The entered value is (" + activeInpVal + ") and it's max is (" + activeInpMax + ")");

if( activeInpVal > activeInpMax ){
   //console 2
   console.log("Error. Value (" + activeInpVal + ") exceeds max (" + activeInpMax + ")");

   pickElement.style.border = '2px solid';
   pickElement.style.outline = 'none';
   pickElement.style.borderColor = '#E60000';
   pickElement.style.boxShadow = '0 0 10px #E60000';
}else{
   console.log("Current value in range");

   pickElement.style.border = '';
   pickElement.style.outline = '';
   pickElement.style.borderColor = '';
   pickElement.style.boxShadow = '';
}
```

**Problem**

Now when I enter my input values 49 or 59 everything works fine
but 9 acts as an error. Here's a screenshot of all 3 scenarios.
[image]

Moreover the console messages in the code above outputs

`The current value in focus is (9) and it's max is (50)` for console 1, and

`Error. Value (9) exceeds max (50)` for console 2.

What could I be missing or doing wrong?

Comment: How do you initiate the check? Can you please create a working code snippet?

Comment: The code is part of a function that's called onload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just put parseInt in your if condition like

```
if( parseInt(activeInpVal) > parseInt(activeInpMax) )
```

it works properly.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. It hadn't actually crossed my mind to parse the values to integers.

Comment: Welcome, it happens some times. :)

Answer (score 3):

So here the concept is if we do

```
console.log( '9' > '50'); //logs true
console.log( 9 > 50);    //logs false
```

so all you need to do to type cast values to integer before comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the the strings to integers to be able to compare them using `>`

```js
var inputs = document.querySelector(".input");
inputs.addEventListener("input", validate, false);

function validate(){
  addEventListener("input", function() {
    var activeInpId = document.activeElement.id;
    var activeInpVal = document.activeElement.value;
    var activeInpMax = document.activeElement.max;
    var pickElement = document.getElementById(activeInpId);
    //console 1
    console.log("The entered value is (" + activeInpVal + ") and it's max is (" + activeInpMax + ")");
    console.log(typeof activeInpVal);
    console.log(typeof activeInpMax);
    if (parseInt(activeInpVal) > parseInt(activeInpMax)) {
      //console 2
      console.log("Error. Value (" + activeInpVal + ") exceeds max (" + activeInpMax + ")");

      pickElement.style.border = '2px solid';
      pickElement.style.outline = 'none';
      pickElement.style.borderColor = '#E60000';
      pickElement.style.boxShadow = '0 0 10px #E60000';
    } else {
      console.log("Current value in range");

      pickElement.style.border = '';
      pickElement.style.outline = '';
      pickElement.style.borderColor = '';
      pickElement.style.boxShadow = '';
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<input class="input" id="inp_1" type="text" numeric-only="" max="50">
<input class="input" id="inp_1" type="text" numeric-only="" max="50">
<input class="input" id="inp_1" type="text" numeric-only="" max="50">
<input class="input" id="inp_1" type="text" numeric-only="" max="50">
<input class="input" id="inp_1" type="text" numeric-only="" max="50">
<input class="input" id="inp_1" type="text" numeric-only="" max="50">
<input class="input" id="inp_1" type="text" numeric-only="" max="50">
```